# Library to draw multiple timespans like in Outlook

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, .net

I am implementing an application that displays an overview of the availability of a limited number of persons. In some sense this is similar to Outlook, if you have a combined view on several people's calendars. In fact it shall become some sort of replacement of Microsoft Outlook, because Outlook always displays short meetings but I'm interested only in long-term (week-wise) absences.

These would be the steps in my application (most of that I will implement myself):

1. get all items from Outlook calendars of the affected persons, plus other sources like personal calendars (Gmail etc.)
2. apply filters, especially: remove all items that are shorter than 2 days
3. display the remaining items on a very rough scale (month to year instead of days): that's where the library comes into play

Here's a graphical representation of what I need:

[image: Calendar representation]

That library or component must

- support .NET (C#)
- support zooming
- support scrolling
- support bars in different colors
- be gratis (free of cost)
- be open source and actively maintained
- allow commercial use

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Chart for WPF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/sfchart) can support this kind of display using the column range chart type- only requirement it won't be able to meet is that it is not open source. There is a community license though if you qualify.

[Sample application code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/205348/ze/WPF_Sample-876738031)

- support .NET (C#) : Yes
- support zooming : Yes
- support scrolling : Yes
- support bars in different colors : Yes
- be gratis (free of cost) : Yes (Community license)
- be open source and actively maintained : Not open source
- allow commercial use : Yes

[image: Chart with Range Column type]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: @Thomas Did you look at this? Do you have any comment?